# How to resolve the error function not defined

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post an image on facebook wall I am using the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : 'XXXXXXXX', // replace your app id here
    channelUrl : 'http://localhost/channel.html', 
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true, 
    xfbml      : true  
    });
};
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function FBLogin(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.authResponse){
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}
function post_on_wall()
{
            var share_name          = 'rohitashav';
            var share_link          = 'http://rohitashavsinghal.com';
            var share_image         = 'http://rohitashavsinghal.com/fb/love.jpg';
            var share_caption       = 'testing';
            var share_description   = 'test desc';

            var share_redirect      = 'http://rohitashavsinghal.com/';


            FB.ui(
            {
                method:         'feed',
                name:           share_name,
                link:           share_link,
                picture:        share_image,
                caption:        share_caption,
                description:    share_description
                //message:      ''
            },
            function(response) 
            {
                if (response && response.post_id) 
                {
                    alert('thanks for sharing!');
                    window.top.location.href = share_redirect;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert('Post was not published.');
                }
            }
}
</script>
```

and Created the Button as follow :

```
<input type="button" value="Post on Wall" onClick="post_on_wall();" />
```

When I click on this Button then in `console` I am getting the following Error :

`post_on_wall is not defined` while I have defined this function

Why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FB.ui` call isn't closed. You need add `);` after the callback function. Without that the `post_on_wall` function is invalid. To be honest I'm really surprised you're not getting an error about that in the console.

Also, above that your call to include the Facebook JS has a misplaced `)`. You need to change `}(document));` to `})(document);`

Comment: if I am closing this then I am getting another error `FB is not defined`

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal Found another issue and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I notice some errors in your code.

1.

```
 (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));`
```

If I get my Javascript right, it should be so:

```
(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
})(document);
```

2. Inside your `FB.UI` call, you have several errors:

   ```
   FB.ui( //method opened
       {
           method:         'feed',
           name:           share_name,
           link:           share_link,
           picture:        share_image,
           caption:        share_caption,
           description:    share_description
           //message:      ''
       },
       function(response) 
       {
           if (response && response.post_id) 
           {
               alert('thanks for sharing!');
               window.top.location.href = share_redirect;
           } 
           else 
           {
               alert('Post was not published.');
           }
   ```

Now, there's no matching closing brace `)` for the opened method call.